# password digest being stored in cleartext using rails4 and use_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I observed that the password digest is not working correctly in my rails 4 app - the password digest is being stored in cleartext in the database.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_secure_password

   validates :password_digest, length: { minimum: 6 }

end
```

My user db migrate file is as follows:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :full_name
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**Edit**
I have bcrypt enabled in Gemfile (I ran bundle install)

```
 gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
```

When I try testing in rails console, I get an invalid hash error:

```
2.2.1 :011 >   user = User.new(full_name: 'abcd', email: 'abc@abc.com', password_digest: 'abcdef')
 => #<User id: nil, full_name: "abcd", email: "abc@abc.com", password_digest: "abcdef", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
2.2.1 :012 > User.find_by(full_name: 'david').try(:authenticate, 'abcdef')
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."full_name" = ? LIMIT 1  [["full_name", "david"]]
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash: invalid hash
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bcrypt-3.1.10/lib/bcrypt/password.rb:60:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activemodel-4.2.4/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb:102:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activemodel-4.2.4/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb:102:in `authenticate'
```

Comment: Do you have `bcrypt` gem enabled in your Gemfile?

Comment: yes -  gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

Answer (score 3):

This is strange, everything should work. Try some examples from the docs in your rails console:

```
user = User.new(name: 'david', password: '', password_confirmation: 'nomatch')
user.save                                                       # => false, password required
user.password = 'mUc3m00RsqyRe'
user.save                                                       # => false, confirmation doesn't match
user.password_confirmation = 'mUc3m00RsqyRe'
user.save                                                       # => true
user.authenticate('notright')                                   # => false
user.authenticate('mUc3m00RsqyRe')                              # => user
User.find_by(name: 'david').try(:authenticate, 'notright')      # => false
User.find_by(name: 'david').try(:authenticate, 'mUc3m00RsqyRe') # => user
```

If `user.save` returns `false` you may look into `user.errors` for failed validation messages.

**EDIT**: @madcow finally sorted it right. Right now you need to convert your plain-text passwords, stored in `password_digest` to bcrypt hashes.

**NOTE: You won't be able to restore plain-text passwords back using this code! Make sure to backup your table before-hand if you need plain-text passwords.**

Try this code for a single user, and, if everything is ok, apply this technique to other users:

```
user = User.find_by(name: 'david')
user.password = user.password_confirmation = user.password_digest
user.save!
```

Here we assign to `user.password` your plain-text password from `user.password_digest`. Since `has_secure_password` redefines `password=` method, your plain-text password should effectively get stored back to `password_digest` column, but now as a hash.

To update all users:

```
User.find_each do |user| 
  user.password = user.password_confirmation = user.password_digest
  user.save!
end
```

Comment: I am able to save users - I can see them in the database.  the password field is cleartext in the database

Comment: It throws error because your `password_digest` is not valid bcrypt hash. I have a feeling that you have overriden `User#password=` method somewhere. Is it complete `User` model that you've shown in your question?

Comment: I do not have a password field, I have named it password_digest

Comment: any thoughts?  the app is still saving pwd in cleartext in the DB

Answer (score 2):

You are accidently saving the cleartext password directly in the password digest field, at least in your console example. That is why the password is stored as cleartext and not hashed.

Instead of typing this in your console:

```
user = User.new(full_name: 'abcd', email: 'abc@abc.com', password_digest: 'abcdef')
```

Enter this:

```
user = User.new(full_name: 'abcd', email: 'abc@abc.com', password: 'abcdef', password_confirmation: 'abcdef')
user.save
```

Then find the user:

```
User.find_by(full_name: 'abcd').try(:authenticate, 'abcdef')
```

Never set the `:password_digest` directly. Always set it through the `:password` and `:password_confirmation` fields.

You are getting that invalid hash error, by the way, because it is trying to decrypt your cleartext (not a valid hash) `:password_digest` value.

Comment: why is the password being saved in cleartext to begin with?  Also, do I need the password_confirmation in my user db migrate file?

Comment: just using password as opposed to password_digest did not give me an error

Comment: That's correct. Do not set `password_digest` directly and you should not get an error. You shouldn't ever need to read/set it directly. That database field is an implementation detail of `has_secure_password` that should remain encapsulated (hidden) from us developers. ;)